# Exclude Special Characters from String Java

Tags: java, special-characters

I am pretty new to Java and i am writing a little Encrypt, Decrypt Tool for School and i wanted to ask how i can
exclude Special Characters from it, i already tried methods like "contains" but i doesn't really work. my code looks like this:

---

```
public void bEncode_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String Input = jTextField1.getText();
    String Output = "";
    String Specialcharacters = "!§$%&/()=?.,-_+*:;";
    jTextField2.setText("Encoding...");
    char c;
    int Number = (Integer) jSpinner1Model.getNumber();
    int asc;
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.length(); i++) {
      if(!Input.contains(Specialcharacters){  
      c = Input.charAt(i);
      asc = (int) c;
      asc = asc + Number;
      if (asc>90) asc = asc-26;
      Output = Output + (char) asc;
      } else {

      }  
    }
    jTextField2.setText(Output);

  }
```

Is there any Method to get this working?

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You need to use regular expressions..

Comment: `.contains(String)` will check it the entire substring `"!§$%&/()=?.,-_+*:;"` is in the input, not each of its individual characters.

Comment: if(!Input.contains(Specialcharacters){ 

should be
    if(!Input.contains(Specialcharacters) ) { 

but apart from that, the "Specialcharacters" is a string, a sequence of characters. It is not just one character. So you are really trying to check if your text contains the entire sequence "!§$%&/()=?.,-_+*:;" as you have written it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression.  For example, the following line will grab only letters and numbers from the given string.

```
String onlyLettersAndNumbers = s.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z]", "");
```